# QGIS 3.2.1 - 3D rendering causes application to crash

Tags: 3d, qgis-3

Whenever I try to render features on 3D map, QGIS crashes. Does anybody have any idea why? The 3D map works ok until I set 3D rendering for a layer.
[image]

Comment: Did you visit the bug report page to see if there's an open ticket for this issue?

Comment: I created one - https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19665